# Symbols not showing up

Tags: equations

My equation doesn't show the symbols: integral, equal, parentheses and etc.. These are the packages I've used and my latex code. Process exited normally. In log, no error messages related to equation, except for "bad box".Any idea on solving this? Thank you.

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{equation} \label{den_abel}
n_{e} (r) =\frac{\lambda n_{c}}{\pi^{2}}\int_{r}^{r_0} 
\frac{\mathit{\phi(x)}}{dx} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-r^{2}}}dx.
\end{equation}`
```

[image]

tested with

`foo $\int(aba)$ bar`

output:

[image]

Process exited normally. Log screenshot:
[image]

[SOLVED]

```
\documentclass{jjap3}
    %\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
    \usepackage{txfonts}

    \usepackage{mathtools} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} \label{den_abel}
    n_{e} (r) =\frac{\lambda n_{c}}{\pi^{2}}\int_{r}^{r_0} 
    \frac{\mathit{\phi(x)}}{dx} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-r^{2}}}dx.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you all for your comments:)

Comment: you will have an error somewhere, put probably in code not shown. Please fix your example so that it is a complete small document that produces the image shown, so that people can debug the problem.

Comment: also show the log file, which probably has either an undefined command error or a "there is no character...." warning, depending on the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: show the log file and what happens with `foo$\int(aba)$ bar`

Comment: Btw: `amsmath` is loaded by `mathtools` already

Comment: Please make the sniplet into a full minimal example, and test only that example. Currently there is no documnet class and no begin/end document

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you all. It is due to the packages redundancy.

Comment: Then please make a comment to your posting as to what solved it, might be useful to others in the future

Answer (score 3):

The `newtx` packages were written in order to remove the numerous weaknesses of `txfonts` (bad character bounding boxes, improper kerning and so on).

By loading `txfonts` after `newtxmath` you get a conflict and no integral sign because `newtxmath` defines (at begin document) a slot for it where `txfonts` has no glyph.

Solution: remove `txfonts`.

You don't need `amssymb`, as `newtxmath` already covers it. Loading `mathtools` will also load `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{den_abel}
n_{e} (r) =
  \frac{\lambda n_{c}}{\pi^{2}}
  \int_{r}^{r_0} \frac{\mathit{\phi(x)}}{dx} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-r^{2}}}\,dx.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for comparison, here is the output with `txfonts`:

[image]

Apart from the different integral symbol (which could be recovered), note the placement of exponents in the two samples (disputable in the bottom one).