# `\int` and `\Sigma` not showing in `kaobook`

Tags: math-mode, equations

Project can be found in Overleaf here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/txwdgwzrfmyk

For some reason, `\int`, `\iint` and `\Sigma` do not show up anymore and I cannot seem to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: please add a small complete document inline here not just use an external link. (your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if that link changes), however your overleaf project shows 43 errors in its log menu.If you get any error don't even look at the output, if you need help resolving an error, ask about that and add the full error text here.

Comment: Thanks for the response David Carlisle. I will take a look at the error log. I added the link because the project is quite extensive, do you know which part would be most useful to add for reference here?

Comment: Perhaps start by fixing the 35 errors instead of just ignoring them. In many cases latex will be set up to be able to compile through errors by making guesses. Those guesses can accumulate into strange things, so don't ignore errors

Comment: You should also learn to use siunitx to typeset units. `\AA` is not how we type Ångstrøm

Comment: The tab:cross table has a lot of negative numbers, look into siunitx on how to format these properly

Comment: All those verb commands in your bib file are probably wrong, especially when you are using biblatex as verb cannot be used inside the argument to a macro. Try replacing with url

Comment: Just for the fun of if, try adding `\end{document} ` just before `\backmatter` this let's us ignore the bibliography etc until the rest compiles.

Comment: After you fixed the table I took a copy. The rest of the 34 reported errors comes from your bad bib file. Fix that and you should be OK. There are a lot of things you really should not do in this doc but that is for another day.

Comment: I really appreciate the indepth analysis, daleif, and I would love to hear some feedback! So far I have made some changes to the original kaobook latex document. The goal of the project is to convert the LaTeX notes of my professor into a teaching book which hopefully can be printed as a hardcopy :-). So any feedback (and criticism) is highly sought after!

Comment: Then you'll probably have to do a lot of clean up before that can become a book. As mentioned use siunitx for units immediately to save a lot of fixing later on. I have helped typesetting a book on special relativity, handling the typesetting

Comment: Also note that @name informs the person that to wrote a comment to them

Comment: In that case daleif I would love your help. To begin with I will clean up the errors and the units. I would like this product to become as perfect as possible before submitting it to my professor for printing!

Comment: @daleif, I have fixed the errors now. The only thing left are 1. Two native notifications that came with the kaobook. This does not cause the error I have as the kaobook overleaf does not have the \int and \Sigma issue, 2. Overfull/underfull hbox and 3. Unused references to other pages I have not implemented yet. Any ideas what else could cause the issue? Most of the document is kept original to kaobook...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue arises because of the `newtxmath` package, although I am not sure about the technical reason. From the [CTAN page of the package](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx), I see that it has been updated only six days ago, so it is quite possible that it was this update which wreaked havoc with your integral signs.

After having read these two other SE posts ([one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444243/symbols-not-showing-up) and [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289363/mathabx-integral-sign-in-newtxmath-style)), I propose two solutions:

- You remove the `newtxmath` package;
- You keep `newtxmath` but use `esint` as well.

Both solutions can be implemented by editing the file `styles/style.sty` of the kaobook template.

Comment: This solved my issue, and I now have working mathmode again. A little sad with the outcome tho, as I really like the newtxmath font :-)

Comment: As soon as I have time, I will try to find a workaround to keep the newtxmath fonts and update the template. I hope to be done before your book is finished :)

Comment: That sounds great, thank you! Alternatively we can look for other fonts if that is easier too. Finally, as we discussed earlier in the project, I found a way to align the title when using \setchapterstyle{kao}. Simply adding \flushright{} in the title aligns the title with the right side line before the chapter number. I think the result looks great :-)

Comment: Dear Tommy, sorry for this lag, but I found a way for you to keep using `newtxmath`: simply don't load the `lmodern` package, as you now do in your main.tex. Apparently it conflicts with the integrals in `newtxmath`. By the way, in the next versions of the kaobook template I will not use `mathpazo` and `newtxmath` anymore, but rather I shall load `newpx`, which seems to offer considerable advantages (in particular, both the text and the math font will be palatino).