# Specific math symbols are not showing in output (parenthesis and plus signs)

Tags: symbols, kaobook

I have a peculiar problem that I have failed to solve.  I have looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444243/symbols-not-showing-up) and have been unable to fix my problem.

Here is an example of my issue:
[image]

Everything looks fine, right?  However, when I have equations with plus or parenthesis, it shows up like this:
[image]

The original code contains  $f(x)=ax+b$. I cannot figure out what is going on.  I am using the kaobook template, found [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook).  I am new to it, and here are the packages I'm using:

```
    \documentclass[
    fontsize=10pt, 
    twoside=false,
    numbers=noenddot,
]{kaobook}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{amsfonts}               
\usepackage{amsmath}                
\usepackage{amssymb}                
\usepackage{centernot}          
\usepackage{mathrsfs}           
\usepackage{mathtools}              
\usepackage{multirow}       
\usepackage{tikz-cd}    
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}

 \begin{document}
  $f(x)=ax+b$
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Hard to tell, without code

Comment: you would need to show an example. also the log should report any missing chanaracters something like `Missing character: There is no ✦ (U+2726) in font TeXGyreTermes:mode=node;scri
`  so please show your log messages if there are any.

Comment: If I try your document I get `! LaTeX Error: Command \refeq already defined` (and the resulting pdf has +)

Comment: From where you get `kaobook.cls`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi there is a link in the question (download the template zip file)

Comment: I edited your two code fragments into an example so that it can be tested, could you confirm that you see the missing symbols (I do not) and if not, edit the example so that it does produce an example of the problem.